# Ideal of ring of endomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

How does one construct a two-sided proper ideal of the endomorphism ring $\operatorname{End}_D(M)$ for some infinite dimensional right module $M$ over some division ring $D$?

Answer (score 1):

One such ideal is that of all endomorphisms which have a finite rank image.

In fact, this is the only such ideal if $M$ is coountably dimensional. For larger dimensions, I am pretty sure one gets one ideal per possible rank.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109982/ideals-in-the-ring-of-endomorphisms-of-a-vector-space-of-uncountably-infinite-di