# Natural Isomorphism between $T_1^1(V)$ and End$(V)$

Tags: differential-geometry, self-learning, tensors

I'm a little stuck on showing that there is a *natural* isomorphism between the $\mathbb{R}$ vector space of $(1,1)$ tensors, and the $\mathbb{R}$ space of of linear maps $T:V\to V$. The hint is define the map $\phi:$End$(V)\to T_1^1(V)$ by $(\phi A)(\omega, X)=\omega(AX).$ I can show that this map is linear and injective, but I'm having trouble proving it's surjective without introducing a basis for $V$.

Comment: If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then this is immediate from the fact that $\dim T^1_1(V) = n^2 = \dim \operatorname{End}(V)$.

Comment: If $V$ is infinite dimensional? The notes I'm reading don't assume finite dimensionality, so I assumed it could be proved more generally.

Comment: @Travis: Natural. Just because, for instance, $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic doesn't mean they're *naturally* so (since they're not!)

Comment: @MikeMiller Perhaps I'm missing something, but OP gives an explicit natural map, and the only outstanding question is whether it is surjective.

Comment: @Travis: Ah, I missed your point, sorry. (I misread your 'this' to mean something else.)

Comment: @MikeMiller Ah yes, 'this' here is meant just to refer to OP's last sentence. Anyway, in the infinite-dimensional case, one can built an explicit endomorphism in the preimage under $\phi$ of any $(1, 1)$-tensor, again using a basis (but again there's no problem with this).

Comment: @Travis: I think you should make these an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space of tensors is $\newcommand\RR{\mathbb R}\newcommand\Bil{\operatorname{Bil}}\Bil(V^*,V;\RR)$, the space of bilinear maps $V^*\times V\to\RR$, and this is the same as $\hom(V^*\otimes V,\RR)$ which,by adjunction, is the same as $\hom(V^*,\hom(V,\RR))=\hom(V^*,V^*)$.

Your map is therefore a function $\phi:\hom(V,V)\to\hom(V^*,V^*)$, up to several natural identifications. In this avatar, it is given by $\phi(A)(\omega)(X)=\omega(AX)$. Computing, we find that this map is an antihomomorphism of $\RR$-algebras; this is no surprise, as this is just transposition.

Now the proper bilateral ideals of $\hom(V,V)$ are indexed by the set of infinite cardinals less than or equal the dimension of $V$ (to each such cardinal $\tau$ we attach the ideal of all maps $V\to V$ with image of dimension less than $\tau$); see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109982/). Given that, the map $\phi$ cannot be bijective when $V$ is infinite dimensional because (I think!) the cardinal of the set of the ideals in $\hom(V,V)$ and in $\hom(V^*,V^*)$ are different.